# Adobe Air Javascript on *.php files

Tags: php, javascript, air

I'm trying to build an Adobe Air app which runs from a PHP file.

Currently I have an `index.html` file which then performs a `location.href` to move to `realfile.php` - this gets round the limitation that a root file has to be `HTML`.

My problem is that the `*.php` files contain JavaScript which in turn make use of Adobe Air code, specifically printing. I overwrite `window.print` to the Air version which works fine in `HTML`.

As soon as the code is copied to the PHP file it doesn't even attempt to call it, yet other JavaScript works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read around a bit more and now know that Air will only run in a HTML page. *Although there is no explanation that I could find that explains why this is...*

**How I think I can fix this:**

My current idea is to add a `RewriteRule` in my htaccess to make PHP files accessible via a `.html` file extension. This should trick Air into thinking it's a HTML document, whilst the server is still able to process the PHP that is on the page.

When I get around to it, I'm more than happy to re-write the app to make it fully AJAX driven, which is what everyone else seems to be doing.